# How to minimize the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + \frac{9}{4}y^2 + 3xy -2x-2y \;\;\;$ s.t. $x,y \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, optimization

My task is to minimize the function

$$f(x,y) = x^2 + \frac{9}{4}y^2 + 3xy -2x-2y \;\;\;$$ subject to $x,y \geq 0$.

Do I need to use Lagrange multipliers in this problem? I tried simply taking the gradient of this function at first from which I got the equations

$$\begin{aligned}2x+3y &=2\\ 6x+9y&=4\end{aligned}$$

at which point I realized I made a mistake probably somewhere. The solution should be according to my reference book: $x=1, y=0$.

Where did I go wrong? Did I make simply a careless mistake somewhere or is my approach wrong?

Thank you for any help=)

Comment: I have the same values as you, I wonder if there is an error in the function.

Comment: Hi @Autolatry I was just about to update my post, I think I found a mistake in the problem setting of my book, I will update my post.

Comment: Ok, your method seems fine to me, locate the critical points; calculate the second partial derviatives to find which would be the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to check for: one is interior minima, which your equations show cannot exist. Then we also need to find edge minima.

Limiting to $x=0$ and $y\ge0$, the function becomes
$$
\frac94y^2-2y
$$
which has a minimum at $y=\frac49$ and value $-\frac49$.

Limiting to $x\ge0$ and $y=0$, the function becomes
$$
x^2-2x
$$
which has a minimum at $x=1$ and value $-1$.

Therefore, the minimum is at $(1,0)$ with value $-1$.

Since the function is $\left(x+\frac32y-1\right)^2+y-1$, it is obviously at least $-1$ for $x,y\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you! =) of course, see it now :)

Answer (score 3):

Since one has $$f(x,y)=x^2+\frac 94 y^2+3xy-2x-2y=\frac 14 (2x+3y-2)^2+y-1,$$
one can see that the minimum is $f(1,0)=-1$ for $x,y\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now =)

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks. Glad to hear that.

Comment: @mathlove: your answer *is* useful, but my comment was also a hint to someone else :-)

Comment: @robjohn: Ah, I see that :)